# why is trim_ws in column not working as expected in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have the following sample of dates that I got from doing the following

```
library(dplyr)
datecols<-df%>%
  select(ReferralDate,BookedDob,ArrestDate)%>%
   mutate_if(is.character, trimws)

         ReferralDate              BookedDob             ArrestDate
1 1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM 12/20/1952 12:00:00 AM                   <NA>
2 1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM  11/5/1995 12:00:00 AM   1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM
3 1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM  6/25/1991 12:00:00 AM   1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM
4 1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM  8/20/1990 12:00:00 AM   1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM
5 1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM  3/15/1955 12:00:00 AM 12/31/2016 12:00:00 AM
6 1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM   2/2/1981 12:00:00 AM   1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM
```

Basically I want to Extract Just the date piece from each of the columns

```
datecols<-sapply(df[,c("ReferralDate","BookedDob","ArrestDate")],substr,1,9)
```

However, when I use this code the output I get is the following 
where the the first rown in BookedDob column is missing the last digit of year and the same for row 5 in arrest date.

```
   ReferralDate BookedDob   ArrestDate 
[1,] "1/1/2017 "  "12/20/195" NA         
[2,] "1/1/2017 "  "11/5/1995" "1/1/2017 "
[3,] "1/1/2017 "  "6/25/1991" "1/1/2017 "
[4,] "1/1/2017 "  "8/20/1990" "1/1/2017 "
[5,] "1/1/2017 "  "3/15/1955" "12/31/201"
[6,] "1/1/2017 "  "2/2/1981 " "1/1/2017 "
```

I thought that by using `triw_ws`I was able to trip all the white spaces. I do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `sapply`, use `lapply` as `sapply` converts to `matrix` if `simplify = TRUE` (by default)

```
lapply(df[,c("ReferralDate","BookedDob","ArrestDate")],substr, 1, 9)
```

---

Also, based on the code showed, `trimws` is applied on the original dataset 'df' and it is not updated but a new object `datecols` is created

Instead it should be

```
lapply(datecols[,c("ReferralDate","BookedDob","ArrestDate")],substr, 1, 9)
```